# C# using LINQ, from a list of objects, create a new list of objects, removing ones whose property is in a list of stings

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object like this -

```
public MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string MyType { get; set; }
}
```

a list of those objects -

```
public List<MyObject> MyObjectList { get; set; }
```

and a list of string like this -

```
public List<string> MyTypeList { get; set; }
```

Using LINQ on `MyObjectList`, I want to create a list of `MyObject` **removing** any `MyObject` that has a `MyObject.MyType` that is in the `MyTypeList`.

Something like this (here are some unsuccessful attempts) -

```
List<MyObject> MyObjectListNEW = MyObjectList.Select(i => i.MyType).Except(MyTypeList).ToList();
List<MyObject> MyObjectListNEW = MyObjectList.Where(i => i.MyType.Except(MyTypeList));
```

Comment: `List<MyObject> MyObjectListNEW = MyObjectList.Where(i => !MyTypeList.Any( t => t == i.MyType)).ToList();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be

```
var results = MyObjectList.Where(m => ! MyTypeList.Contains(m.MyType)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var MyObjectList = new List<MyObject>();
var MyTypeList = new List<string>();
var results = MyObjectList.Where(m => !MyTypeList.Any(t => m.MyType == t)).ToList();
```

Comment: Instead of `.Any(t => expr == t)` it is often better to write `.Contains(expr)`. The latter can go to an ordinary instance method if this is used directly on an `ICollection<>` or similar (which is the case in the current question), or can go to Linq's extension method `Contains<TSource>` in situations where we have nothing better than an `IEnumerable<>` as source.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var results = MyObjectList.Where(m =>  !MyTypeList.Contains(m.MyType)).ToList();
```